# People field: Name Vs. Name (With Presence) / Issue with SAML and AD users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2019

Looking for some help with a People field issue and my Google powers have failed me.

Does anyone know if there is a difference between a People and Group filed if it is set to Name instead of Name (With Presence)?  Specifically with copy / pasting an email address into the field in grid view?

We have AzureAD auth, SAML, setup (standard Move-spuser for the user migration) but when users copy / paste email addresses from excel into grid view the user is added to the User Info List in domain\username format, not in the expected *junk*|AzureAD|EmailAddress format.  This also sets their domain\username account to active in the UserInfo table, or creates a new account in the table for them in the domain\username format.

Any help would be AWSEOME!

Answer (score 0):

People field set as **Name (With Presence)** will display an additional icon in front of username as shown in the image below, which is available only in classic experience:

[image]

Technically, the icon represents the presence status of the user, for example, it gets lighted up when the user is identified “Online”.

Besides that, there is no difference between People fields set as **Name** and those set as **Name (With Presence)**.

Users in People field or the User Information List will always display in the format of “**Account name**” or “**Display name**” (`domain\username` or just `username`), which is the expected behavior, even when they are added using email addresses. There is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks Chelsea, but the users are causing issues in the farm, workflows are failing like crazy because the people picker is adding the user as domain\username in the user info list, and this account does not have a profile in the UPS, so when the workflow goes to grab info about the user from the UPS it fails.  Users in the UPS are all in the SAML format, and users in the User Info Table are in SAML format, but when the people picker adds the user to the user info list as domain\user, it adds them to the user info table as an active user in domain\user format, thus creating duplicate accounts

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan See the comment section in this article here talking about similar scenarios: https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/mapping-user-profiles-for-saml-users-with-an-ad-import-in-sharepoint-2013/

According to which, it might happen when you have or at one time had Windows authentication configured for your web applications. So the solution here might be going completely without Integrated Windows authentication, or you will need some manual work matching those user profiles instead.

Comment: @JoshMcClanahan See another post here for reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3cd644eb-8507-4023-b8d2-781b93c05569/adfs-user-to-equal-windows-user?forum=SP2016